# Javascript Object negative number

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Create object adjustementType inside script tag in MVC 5 partial view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var adjustementType = { -1:'Rate Decrease', 1: 'Rate Increase' };
</script>
```

but getting following error **"Expected identifier, string or number"** . The error is thrown on area -1 & 1 field.

Comment: You have it the wrong way around - `var adjustementType = { 'RateDecrease': -1, 'RateIncrease': 1 };`

Comment: :) simple things takes more time to fix. Thanks for help Stephen it's workings now . Thinking  Why it wont work the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use strings with spaces because you are defining variables and you also should turn type around like this:

```
var adjustementType = { RateDecrease: -1, RateIncrease: 1 };
alert(adjustementType.RateDecrease); //-1
```

This is because you are actually defining enums.

**EDIT:** You can use strings with spaces too but then you are dealing with them like arrays. But I think this doesn't make any sense.

```
var enumtype = { "-1": "Rate Decrease", "1" : "Rate Increase"};
alert(enumtype["1"]); //Rate Increase
alert(enumtype["-1"]); //Rate Decrease
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `-1` is not valid identifier you need to take such keys into quotes when you define an object properties:

```
var adjustementType = { '-1': 'Rate Decrease', 1: 'Rate Increase' };
```

then you will be able to access it using bracket notation:

```
alert(adjustementType[-1]);
```

Comment: { '-1': 'Rate Decrease', 1: 'Rate Increase' } invalid JSON
{ "-1": "Rate Decrease", "1": "Rate Increase" } valid